# Take snapshot of JPanel and display it in a new window

Tags: java, swing, snapshot

I created a chart extending `JPanel` and overriding `paint()` method. When I click on this panel I'd like to create a "snapshot" of the chart and open it in a new `JFrame`.

I tried by creating a buffered image as shown below, but the problem is that when I resize the window I loose lot of quality.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SnapshotDemo extends JPanel{

    private JComponent src;
    private BufferedImage img;
    private final JFrame f = new JFrame();

    public SnapshotDemo(JComponent src) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        this.src = src;
        this.img = takeSnapshot(src);
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }

    public void display(){
        f.setContentPane(this);
        f.setSize(1000,600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static BufferedImage takeSnapshot(JComponent src){
        BufferedImage i = new BufferedImage(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = i.createGraphics();
        src.printAll(g2);
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;
                int stepx = getWidth()/5;
                int stepy = getHeight()/5;
                for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                    g2.drawLine(x, y, x+stepx, y+stepy);
                    x+=stepx;
                    y+=stepy;
                }
                g2.setPaint(Color.red);
                g2.drawOval(getWidth()/2-30, getHeight()/2-30, 60, 60);
            }
        };
        p.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}  
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                SnapshotDemo d = new SnapshotDemo(p);
                d.display();
            }
        });
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setContentPane(p);
        f.setSize(1000, 600);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any idea about how to handle this issue better? Is there a way to avoid the use of images (`BufferedImage` etc...)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a snapshot of the chart model and use this model in the new frame.

Comment: Can you please explain better what you mean? Sorry but I'm not a programmer and I need "for dummies" explanations :D

Comment: Swing is based on the model-view-controller architecture and thus views only display a model state. Thus you can take a snapshot of the model and use it with another instance of the view and it will be resizable. For details about mvc take a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html and maybe https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2013/07/20/the-mvc-pattern-implemented-with-java-swing/

Comment: But how can I take a snapshot of JPanel model and pass it to a new JFrame? JPanel seems not to have `getModel()` method like other components.

Comment: That's right a JPanel doesn't have a model. What library do you use for the chart? Maybe we can find an answer there.

Comment: No library, I created the chart from scratch, starting from `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

> but the problem is that when I resize the window I loose lot of quality.

When you resize any image you lose quality. This is called pixilation. If you don't want to loose quality the don't resize the image larger.

> I created a chart extending JPanel and overriding paint() method.

Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` and don't forget the `super.paintComponent(...)` at the start of the method.

But why are you even creating a custom panel. Just use the `BufferedImage` to create an `ImageIcon` and then add the `ImageIcon` to a `JLabel`. This way the image will always be displayed at its actual size so resizing the window will not affect the quality.

Comment: This is what I did at first. But I was wondering if there was a way to enlarge the snapshot without losing quality, since it would be very helpful for the user. I know this is probably not possible through images (`Image`,`ImageIcon` or whatever), so my question is if there are other way to achieve my goal.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. You just can't make an image bigger without losing quality. Have you ever tried zooming on a picture you take with your camera?